# regex pattern in python for parsing HTML title tags

Tags: python, html, regex, web-scraping

I am learning to use both the `re` module and the `urllib` module in python and attempting to write a simple web scraper. Here's the code I've written to scrape just the title of websites:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import urllib
import re

urls=["http://google.com","https://facebook.com","http://reddit.com"]

i=0

these_regex="<title>(.+?)</title>"
pattern=re.compile(these_regex)

while(i<len(urls)):
        htmlfile=urllib.urlopen(urls[i])
        htmltext=htmlfile.read()
        titles=re.findall(pattern,htmltext)
        print titles
        i+=1
```

This gives the correct output for Google and Reddit but not for Facebook - like so:

```
['Google']
[]
['reddit: the front page of the internet']
```

This is because, I found that on Facebook's page the `title` tag is as follows: `<title id="pageTitle">`. To accomodate for the additional `id=`, I modified the `these_regex` variable as follows: `these_regex="<title.+?>(.+?)</title>"`. But this gives the following output:

```
[]
['Welcome to Facebook \xe2\x80\x94 Log in, sign up or learn more']
[]
```

How would I combine both so that I can take into account any additional parameters passed within the `title` tag?

Comment: You really want to use a proper HTML parser; I recommend you look at BeautifulSoup instead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/72746

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You are using a regular expression, and matching HTML with such expressions get too complicated, too fast.

Use a HTML parser instead, Python has several to choose from. I recommend you use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), a popular 3rd party library.

BeautifulSoup example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.read(), from_encoding=response.info().getparam('charset'))
title = soup.find('title').text
```

Since a `title` tag itself doesn't contain other tags, you can get away with a regular expression here, but as soon as you try to parse nested tags, you *will* run into hugely complex issues.

Your specific problem can be solved by matching additional characters within the `title` tag, optionally:

```
r'<title[^>]*>([^<]+)</title>'
```

This matches 0 or more characters that are *not* the closing `>` bracket. The '0 or more' here lets you match both extra attributes and the plain `<title>` tag.

Answer (score 43):

It is recommended that you use [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) or any other parser to parse HTML, but if you *badly want regex* the following piece of code would do the job.

**The regex code:**

```
<title.*?>(.+?)</title>
```

**How it works:**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**Produces:**

```
['Google']
['Welcome to Facebook - Log In, Sign Up or Learn More']
['reddit: the front page of the internet']
```

Comment: The question mark on the `e` makes this match `<titl>Google</title>` too. You probably want to get rid of that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks for pointing that out, I'll fix it although I reckon you'd never meet a `<titl>Google</title>` in your whole programming life

Comment: You'd be surprised how sloppy some HTML is. The point was more that the question mark isn't useful there.

Comment: Why the `\s?` here; the `.*?` will already match the space. If you wanted the space to be explicit, why not use `\b` to match the boundary instead (between `e` and `>` or `e` and a space), or use a non-capturing optional group `<title(?:\s.+?)?>`.

Comment: Where did you get that nice 'How it works' visualization from?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to identify all the htlm tags, you can use this

```
batRegex = re.compile(r'(<[a-z]*>)')
m1=batRegex.search(html)
print batRegex.findall(yourstring)
```

Comment: What about tags with attributes? The above won't work for `<a class='link'>url</a>`.

Answer (score 0):

You could scrape a bunch of titles with a couple lines of [gazpacho](https://github.com/maxhumber/gazpacho):

```py
from gazpacho import Soup

urls = ["http://google.com", "https://facebook.com", "http://reddit.com"]

titles = []
for url in urls:
    soup = Soup.get(url)
    title = soup.find("title", mode="first").text
    titles.append(title)
```

This will output:

```py
titles
['Google',
 'Facebook - Log In or Sign Up',
 'reddit: the front page of the internet']
```