# Remove only specific table tags from HTML files using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I am working on parsing hundreds of HTML documents using BeautifulSoup package. My code is able to parse entire documents very well.

I want to remove the content of all table tags depending upon on a condition. Since few tables (as per HTML tags) might not actually be tables, rather text presented inside a table. If the content of a table has more than 75% of characters as numbers, I would like to treat it as actual table and remove it, otherwise I would like to keep it.

I am new to Python and not sure how can I remove entire content of only specific  tables.

Suppose my HTML document is:

```
<document>
<table>
100
</table>
<text>
Hello Word
</text>
<table>
Test
</table>
</document>
```

Following code will generate content of entire HTML document i.e.

```
100
Hello Word 
Test
```

What I want is:

```
Hello Word 
Test
```

Please note that code also contains one function that is useful to check if text is useful or not. I am counting both alphabetical as well as numerical characters separately because there could be a lot of white spaces and other garbage characters.

Please help me in removing tables which are not useful i.e which contain more than 75% numerical characters. Please also note that table need not to be direct child of document.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import html5lib
def isTableUseful(text): #Returns True if table is to be included
    try:
        countAlpha = 0
        countNumeric = 0
        for char in text:
            if char.isalpha():
                countAlpha += 1
            if char.isnumeric():
                countNumeric += 1
        FracNumeric = countNumeric/(countNumeric+countAlpha)
        return FracNumeric < 0.75
    except:
        return False
soup = BeautifulSoup("<document><table>100</table><text>Hello Word</text><table>Test</table></document>", "html5lib")
print ('\n'.join([e.encode("utf-8") for e in soup.recursiveChildGenerator() if isinstance(e,unicode) and e.strip()!=""]))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
def should_remove(text):
    count_number = 0
    for c in text:
        if c.isnumeric():
            count_number = count_number + 1    
    return count_number / len(text) > 0.75

# TODO: Initialize soup

# Remove all undesired tags from soup.
[s.extract() for s in soup.find_all('table') if should_remove(s.get_text().strip())]

#  Extract, format and print remaining text in soup.
# in Python3
[print(s.strip()) for s in soup.get_text().split('\n') if s.strip() != '']

# OR in Python2: 
result = [s.strip() for s in soup.get_text().split('\n') if s.strip() != '']
for line in result:
    print line
```

Edit: Corrected list comprehension, extract text from soup.

Comment: @mhi..Unfortunately, one statement in your code which removes all undesired tags from soup does not seem to work properly. I get [u'100Hello WordTest'] as the output.

Comment: @Ankit Without more information about what you code you are currently running, it's difficult for me to help. The code I posted runs fine on python 3.4.1.

Comment: I am using Python 2.7.5.

Comment: @mhi..Above code did not solve my problem. find_all('table') will search only for table tags. What I needed was content from table tags which are textual in nature as well text from other tags (as explained in my question). Unfortunately, files that I have are very messy and very big (~25-50 MB). There are so many tags which are not closed and this is creating problem with any built-in parser including HTML, XML, LXML. I could not think of a better solution than doing it manually and writing my own functions.

Answer (score -1):

You can check this: [regex pattern in python for parsing HTML title tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045955/regex-pattern-in-python-for-parsing-html-title-tags)

You have to adjust this below, from that link, to meet your needs:

```
title = soup.find('title').text
```

Then iterate all over them.
Or you can do regex, as suggested on that link too.